# Flutter. GetX the improper use of a GetX has been detected. with the RxList

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```dart
RxList<ParticipantModel> participantList = RxList.empty();
........
 Obx(  <==== [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.  with the RxList
              () => NCChipEditableList<ParticipantModel>(
                key: const Key('StudioEditPage txt_add_main_actors'),
                title: 'txt_add_main_actors'.tr.format(
                  [MediaConst.maxArtistTagLength],
                ),
                addButtonText: 'txt_add_actor'.tr,
                chipList: controller.media.participantList,
                maxTextLength: MediaConst.maxArtistTagLength,
                onAddChip: controller.onAddParticipant,
                onDeleteChip: controller.onDeleteParticipant,
                onEditedChip: controller.onEditedParticipant,
              ),
            ),
```

actually, i dont understand how to resolve this problem. I use initiated RxList as the parameter NCChipEditableList

Answer (score 0):

`Obx` is made to update when an `Rx<T>` observable variable is used inside of it, so it should be used like this:

```
// controller
Rx<String> txt = "text".obs;

// view
Obx(() => Text(txt.value)), // works fine
```

if no `Rx<R>` variables are used inside of it :

```
// view
Obx(() => Text("normal raw text")), // throws the error
```

Then your error will be thrown from the `Getx` library to inform you that since there is nothing to update inside the `Obx`, there is no need to use it.

you should set your widget directly without wrapping with `Obx` if you don't need it.

Comment: i know it, in my example i use RxList<ParticipantModel> participantList inside Obx

Comment: you didn't pass the `value`, you passed the whole Rx<List> so it detect it as it doesn't  exists inside the `Obx`

Comment: changed chipList: controller.media.participantList to chipList: controller.media.participantList.value. Works